# Changing values from localstorage on click event isn't always working

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm doing a to-do list application and I want it show the tasks on the page and also save them in local-storage so it's there when the page is refreshed. I added the option to delete and mark tasks as complete which change the element color and change the value of the 'done' property that is stored in local-storage.

By default the 'done' property is supposed to be false and that changes when you click on the element. One time it works and you can see the value changing on the browser tools, and other times when you click on different elements or delete them it doesn't.

The error that I'm getting is:

> TypeError: items[index] is undefined. [line 73 in JS Fiddle]

https://jsfiddle.net/84rkq0yj/1/

This is the function that I used but I couldn't identify the reason `items[index]` becomes `undefined`.

```
function completeList(e) {
  const targetLi = e.target.parentElement;
  const lisArr = Array.from(list.children);
  const index = lisArr.indexOf(targetLi);
  const taskLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  taskLi.forEach(li => {
    if(li.contains(e.target)){
      li.classList.toggle('done');
      items[index].done = !items[index].done;
      populateList(items, list);
      localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    }
  });
};
list.addEventListener('click', completeList);
```

Comment: Add a `debugger` statement and walk through all your variables. Make sure target is what you expect it to be

Comment: @PatrickEvans The problem was from the `const targetLi` as the other answer suggested. I initialized it in a wrong way. Regarding the length, I have a commented a line of code that clears `items` if the length of `list.children` is 0 since I didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may happen when the click event fires on a `li` element instead of a `span`.

The following code assumes that event is fired on `span` element that is a child of `li` element.

```
function completeList(e) {
  const targetLi = e.target.parentElement;
  ...
}
```

When the event is fired for `li` element, the wrapping `div` is assigned to `targetLi` variable and that breaks things.

Adding a check for the type of element in the event handler should help:

```
function completeList(e) {
  const targetLi = e.target.tagName === 'LI' ? e.target : e.target.parentElement;
  ...
}
```